# Respect Validation and reset connection

Tags: php, respect-validation

I'm using the [Respect\Validation](http://documentup.com/Respect/Validation/#) library and I cannot get meaningful exceptions to print out apart from the first message.

This code gives me an error:

```
try {
    $foo = \Respect\Validation\Validator::notEmpty();
    $foo->assert('');
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo $e->getFullMessage();
}
```

> Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

However, this code works fine:

```
try {
    $foo = \Respect\Validation\Validator::notEmpty();
    $foo->check('');
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo $e->getMainMessage();
}
```

I've tried turning off Xdebug but that didn't solve the problem. My version of PHP is 5.4.3.

Comment: @zerkms If by that you mean the Apache error log then there's nothing related to this issue there.

Comment: what `Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` means then? It's your browser didn't get the response from a webserver. It means something really bad happened during request processing